# What is a good way for someone to purchase Mining Bonds?

Tags: cloud-mining

GLBSE is down, and so is [PureMining](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=65569.0), which used to give deterministic hash rate yields.

What are the alternatives? If someone wants to invest in Bitcoin mining, but doesn't want to own & operate a mining rig, what is a good way for him to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://btct.co/ which is a virtual stock exchange similar to GLBSE.

Comment: Are there good mining bonds? Anything deterministic and reputable?

Comment: I hold Cognitive bonds. Up until now I got payed regularly. Whether this is the best investment I don't know. (I'm not affiliated with Cognitive).